# R: Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404 when scraping image URLs

Tags: r, rvest

I'm building out a scraping solution in R to fetch images programatically from the Web.

```
#Step 1: Get all the google search result URLs
query <- paste("Djeco", "DJ01801", "image", sep = " ")%>%URLencode()
  google_urls <- paste0("https://www.google.gr/search?q=", query, "&tbm=isch") %>%
                 read_html() %>%
                 html_nodes(xpath = "//td/a") %>% 
                 html_attr("href") %>%
                 `[`(str_detect(., "/url\\?")) %>%
                 strsplit("=|\\&") %>%
                 sapply(`[`, 2)
  google_urls <- google_urls%>%unique()

#Step 2: Retreive the dedicated image URLs
image_urls <- vector()
for(j in 1:length(google_urls)) {temp <- read_html(google_urls[j]) %>%
                                         html_nodes("img") %>%
                                         html_attr("src")
                                image_urls <- c(image_urls,temp)}
```

I hit the below error on Step 2. How may I resolve this?

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.
```

Comment: Site structures change, product pages expire, having 404 page not found errors are quite common, no?  What is your desired result in this case or what would you consider "resolved"? Loop continuing despite errors? Attempt to retrieve failed page content from archive.org Timemachine?